# How to show a column name in excel if a condition is met (eliminating the blank ones)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have the following table:

[image]

I need the `Result` row to show the name of `Fruits` if their value is greater than 1. I have the following function for `R18`, it gets dynamic when stretched to the succeeding rows:

```
=IF(AND(R16>0,R15<>O18,R15<>P18,R15<>Q18),R15,IF(AND(S16>0,S15<>O18,S15<>P18,S15<>Q18),S15,IF(AND(T16>0,T15<>O18,T15<>P18,T15<>Q18),T15,"")))
```

However, as you can see in the picture there is a gap in results which is because `Peach`'s value is `0` and breaks the functions.

Here's my intended result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try,

In `R18`, formula copied across right until blank:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($R$15:$X$15,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A$1:$G$1)/($R$16:$X$16>0),COLUMN(A1))),"")
```